# DistinctUntilChange not working with switchMap?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to implement the rxjs function   **distinctUntilChanged** but no work ...

```
   public searchVal(val: string) {
        this.suggestions = (new Observable((observer: Observer<string>) => {
          observer.next(val);
        })).pipe(
          takeUntil(this.destroy$),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          switchMap((query: string) => {
            if (query) {
              console.log('query query' , query) 
            }
            return of([]);
          })
        );
      }
```

but this doesn't work I don't know why? I also set up debounceTime but it doesn't work either?

My plan is not to send the same values.

Comment: Are you subscribing?

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Observable((observer: Observer<string>) => {
  observer.next(val);
})
```

This is just `of(val)` except for completing the observable. Also, as a rule of thumb the `takeUntil` operator should come *last*. That changes your code to

```js
public searchVal(val: string) {
  this.suggestions = of(val).pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(query => of([])),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  );
}
```

However, this does not do at all what you probably think it does. Every time you call `searchVal`, this will create a new observable and assign it to `suggestions`, rendering the `distinctUntilChanged` useless as only ever a single value will flow through the pipe.

What you more likely want to do is create

```js
private readonly input$ = new Subject<string>();

public readonly suggestions$ = defer(() => this.input$).pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(() => of([])),
  takeUntil(defer(() => this.destroy$)),
);
```

and then

```js
public searchVal(val: string) {
  this.input$.next(val);
}
```

The `defer()` calls are just a trick to avoid declaration order issues. If you instead assign `suggestions$` e.g. in the constructor you won't need the `defer`s.